# Android jni how to access file that relative to my cpp file?

Tags: android, c++, file-io, java-native-interface, readfile

I got a jni project, and the file structure in jni like this:

```
jni
 |--Android.mk
 |--Application.mk
 |--com_example_jnifile_Filer.h
 |--jnifile.cpp
 |--res.txt
```

and the code in jnifile.cpp like this:

```
#include "com_example_jnifile_Filer.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

jstring Java_com_example_jnifile_Filer_n_1get_1string(JNIEnv* env, jclass obj) {
    ifstream in("res.txt");
    if (!in) {
        return env->NewStringUTF("can't open file res.txt!");
    }
    string s;
    getline(in, s);
    return env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
}
```

and the content in res.txt is:

```
hello world!
```

so, the question is, how to access the file res.txt through c++ code?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

try to use below to read your file:

```
ifstream in;
in.open ("names.txt");
if(!(in.is_open())){
   return env->NewStringUTF("can't open file res.txt!");
}
string s;
getline(in, s);
return env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
```